# How could updating ssl certs cause node forever to stop?

Tags: node.js, nginx, ssl, lets-encrypt, forever

I just went through some very strange debugging after running

```
sudo systemctl stop nginx

sudo /opt/bitnami/letsencrypt/lego --tls --email="..." --domains="..." --path="/opt/bitnami/letsencrypt" renew --days 90

sudo systemctl start nginx
```

I was getting a 502 error, and many errors of the form

```
[error] 25208#25208: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client
```

I had multiple domains running on this server, but I only updated one of their ssl certs. The other domains were still up, but the one that was updated began erroring out with 502. After endless Google searches, it kept pointing to an IPv6 issue, and changing localhost to 127.0.0.1 in the nginx config, or to a mismatch of ports between nginx and node. It turned out that somehow forever had just stopped, without leaving any indication, e.g. I couldn't find anything from today in `~/.forever`. I just want to know if i'm missing anything obvious, this was not the first time that I updated ssl certs, and I did the exact same thing last time without this happening.

Comment: I feel this question is like a 100 piece puzzle where you've only provided some random 5 pieces and ask us how the the final picture looks like. There is no description of the overall setup, no config, no logs, no ... - basically nothing really useful here to understand your problem and even less to debug it.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich that's fair, I was just looking to see if anyone had ever encountered anything like this before. I maybe didn't make it clear that the solution to the problem was running 'forever start app.js', but that I could not figure out what stopped it in the first place (there was no log entry from forever, nor my own apps logging on why it stopped running.) I added all of the bits about nginx for anyone in the future frustratingly googling this same problem thinking that's the issue, when it's really not at all related.